# Help "ruby-fying" this SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just need some help to finish turning this SQL :

```
SELECT us.name, pt.task, sum(hours) 
  FROM records
  INNER JOIN project_tasks pt ON records.task_id = pt.id   
  INNER JOIN users us ON records.user_id = us.id 
  GROUP BY user_id, task
```

into Ruby SQL similar to this:

```
test = Record.sum( :hours ,
                      :joins => :project_task,
                      :joins => :user,
                      :conditions => {""} )
```

ive got this far above but im having trouble working out the conditions.
i got the above from converting the SQL to this:

```
test = Record.select( "name, task, sum(hours)").joins( :project_task).joins( :user).group("user_id, task" )
```

im new to Ruby so any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old style variant will be:

```
Record.find(:all,
            :select => 'name, task, sum(hours)',
            :joins => 'INNER JOIN project_tasks pt ON records.task_id = pt.id INNER JOIN users us ON records.user_id = us.id',
            :group => 'user_id, task')
```

Comment: I tried your code and changed it to the following: `record = Effort.find(:all, 
                      :select => "users.full_name, project_tasks.task_name, hours", 
                      :joins => [:user, :project_task], 
                      :group => "user_id, project_tasks.task_name")`